# How to predict word using trained CBOW

Tags: neural-network, nlp, deep-learning, word2vec, language-model

I have a question about CBOW prediction. Suppose my job is to use 3 surrounding words w(t-3), w(t-2), w(t-1)as input to predict one target word w(t). Once the model is trained and I want to predict a missing word after a sentence. Does this model only work for a sentence with four words which the first three are known and the last is unknown? If I have a sentence in 10 words. The first nine words are known, can I use 9 words as input to predict the last missing word in that sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word2vec CBOW mode typically uses symmetric windows around a target word. But it simply averages the (current in-training) word-vectors for all words in the window to find the 'inputs' for the prediction neural-network. Thus, it is tolerant of asymmetric windows – if there are fewer words are available on either side, fewer words on that side are used (and perhaps even zero on that side, for words at the front/end of a text).

Additionally, during each training example, it doesn't always use the maximum-window specified, but some random-sized window up-to the specified size. So for `window=5`, it will sometimes use just 1 on either side, and other times 2, 3, 4, or 5. This is done to effectively overweight closer words.

Finally and most importantly for your question, word2vec doesn't really do a full-prediction during training of "what exact word does the model say should be heat this target location?" In either the 'hierarchical softmax' or 'negative-sampling' variants, such an exact prediction can be expensive, requiring calculations of neural-network output-node activation levels proportionate to the size of the full corpus vocabulary.

Instead, it does the much-smaller number-of-calculations required to see how strongly the neural-network is predicting the actual target word observed in the training data, perhaps in contrast to a few other words. In hierarchical-softmax, this involves calculating output nodes for a short encoding of the one target word – ignoring all other output nodes encoding other words. In negative-sampling, this involves calculating the one distinct output node for the target word, plus a few output nodes for other randomly-chosen words (the 'negative' examples).

In neither case does training know if this target word is being predicted in preference over all other words – because it's not taking the time to evaluate all others words. It just looks at the current strength-of-outputs for a real example's target word, and nudges them (via back-propagation) to be slightly stronger.

The end result of this process is the word-vectors that are usefully-arranged for other purposes, where similar words are close to each other, and even certain relative directions and magnitudes also seem to match human judgements of words' relationships.

But the final word-vectors, and model-state, might still be just mediocre at predicting missing words from texts – because it was only ever nudged to be better on individual examples. You could theoretically compare a model's predictions for every possible target word, and thus force-create a sort of ranked-list of predicted-words – but that's more expensive than anything needed for training, and prediction of words like that isn't the usual downstream application of sets of word-vectors. So indeed most word2vec libraries don't even include any interface methods for doing full target-word prediction. (For example, the original word2vec.c from Google doesn't.)

A few versions ago, the Python `gensim` library added an experimental method for prediction, `[predict_output_word()][1]`. It only works for negative-sampling mode, and it doesn't quite handle window-word-weighting the same way as is done in training. You could give it a try, but don't be surprised if the results aren't impressive. As noted above, making actual predictions of words isn't the usual real goal of word2vec-training. (Other more stateful text-analysis, even just large co-occurrence tables, might do better at that. But they might not force word-vectors into interesting constellations like word2vec.)